# How Do They Make Surface Mount Capacitors and Resistors?

Tags: manufacturing

With the ever decreasing size of surface mount resistors and capacitors, how do they make such small components?

[image]

Comment: Elves. Tiny ones.

Comment: Be aware of thermal-distortion caused by tiny resistors. Assuming an accurate thermal model for a 1 millimeter cube resistor is the same as 1 mm cube of silicon, the thermal timeconstant is 11.4 milliSeconds. The F3dB is about 15 Hertz; this means low frequency energy will fully heat or not-heat the resistor, and if this resistor is Rfeedback of the opamp gain-set network, the gain will be varying and any higher tones will be AM-modulated by the slower tones. Not what a person wants from music.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a lot of written material on the net about discrete component manufacturing.  If a picture is worth a thousand words, is a video is worth even more?

[Here is a very informative video about ceramic capacitor manufacturing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFEYuaY35Vo).  It starts with a roll-to-roll process with ceramic-coated tape that is patterned, stacked, and laminated.  The layers are then mechanically diced into individual components.  A large part of the process occurs AFTER the near grain-of-salt sized components are separated, including putting on the contacts.

The [video for resistor manufacturing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wshRwO0MCSU) is not as impressive, since it's just an animated representation, but it does show all of the steps.  The process begins with a ceramic substrate that is molded with a grid of grooves on one side so that it can eventually be snapped into individual components. There are  [screen printing steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2OeHTHMrvk&t=6s) for the resistance layer, contacts, encapsulation, etc.  The process also includes laser trimming the resistance value and separating the parts, but I couldn't find any videos of these steps in an actual production line.

Given the precision and the number of steps required to create these tiny components, it's amazing that they cost so little.  I guess that's the magic of economies of scale.

(And don't forget that after the parts are made, you still have to [put them onto tape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1pNGTGCpUE) so that they can be easily accessed by the [pick and place machine.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOZe16eoR9g))

Comment: Murata Manufacturing Co., Ltd.   has developed the world's smallest 008004 size

Comment: I bet they'll lose a few by people inhaling them :-) .  I would love to see that manufacturing process.

Comment: The density of smaller parts outside of the packaging  is amazing- it's quite possible to hold a million pieces in the palm of your hand. The crazy small Murata parts Tony mentions- 32,000,000 would fit in a 50mm (less than 2") cube.

Comment: must be a bitch to try and read the part number on one of those ... lol

Comment: Good question, but why did you ask and answer your own question in the same hour?

Comment: It's actually encouraged by Stack Exchange in cases where you have what you think is a good question and a good answer.  See: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/